# pgpool stability issues

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgpool

I am using pgpool-II 3.3.1 to load balance connections to my postgres 9.3. I am experiencing an ocassional stability issue where clients are not able to connect to pgpool (but they are able to connect directly to postgres). I am no where near any configured connections limit. What's strange is the following:

1. pgpool shows that some clients are still connected (has 1 near them in the list) even though clients were shut down hours ago (I have 60 seconds timeout for idle connections)
2. pgpool shows that there are available connections (0 near them in the list) but still clients cannot connect
3. There are a few queries hanging in the db (should be short but stack for minutes). Those are SELECT and no reason to have any locks. Once I kill those queries in postgres, pgpool can get connections again. (remember I could connect directly to db at any time, pgpool was the issue)

Did anyone see any of these issues hapenning? Does anyone have a stable pgpool instllation so I would know it is mature enough?